# How can you set up Eclipse to remove trailing whitespace when saving a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I am running Eclipse 3.6 (Helios 20110218-0911) on Ubuntu 11.04. Under Preferences, I have gone to the following panel:

JavaScript -> Editor -> Save Actions.

The "Additional actions" checkbox is checked and "Remove trailing whitespaces on all lines" is selected.

[image]

Nevertheless, when I save my JavaScript file in Eclipse, there is still trailing whitespace at the end of my lines.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'Save Actions' for JavaScript is available in the JavaScript project(the project with JavaScript nature) only.
(If you can see 'Convert to JavaScript Project' in 'Configure' menu when right-click the project, try it)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I use both Java and JavaScript in the same project, so I'm not sure that this will work for me, as my project is currently configured as a Java project.

Though I don't know why it should matter what the nature of my project is to Eclipse.

Comment: I was able to change my project to a faceted project with both Java and Javascript selected as Project Facets.

Comment: Here's how I did it in Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2):
1. Select Project / Properties from the menu.
2. Click on Project Facets.
3. Check "JavaScript" and click OK.
4. Select Project / Properties from the menu again.
5. There should now be a JavaScript section. Go to Editor / Save Actions under this section and configure it there.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same problem. The only way I found is to convert your project to Javascript project. Right click your project folder in the Explorer, choose [Configure] -> [Convert to Javascript project] and the Javascript Save Action will start to work.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to convert it back. 
Since it's not a big problem for me, the way Converting it to javascript project indeed helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest Eclipse - 
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200

The default key-binding <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>, which binds to the function "Removes the trailing whitespace of each line" will remove trailing space chars for the entire file.

(The key-binding <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> is probably already there in many earlier releases as well.)